# Is there an ansi escape sequence to set colors for empty areas?

Tags: ansi-escape

I've seen a few overviews of ansi sequences. In testing I've found that the foreground color and background color settings apply only to sections with text, resulting in some jarring contrast, especially for syntax highlighting. Is there a sequence to specify non text area colors / turn off this rendering behavior?

I've also found mention of these two sequences, but everywhere I've found specifies these are implementation defined, no mention of any particular syntax to go along with. I tried using it as though it were an rgb sequence, had no impact.

```
\033[49
\033[39
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to sort out.
[image]

Here's what I'd be after.
[image]
Currently using a windows console, a portable solution would be preferable.

Comment: `\033[39` and 49 are supposed to specify to use respectively the default foreground and background colors, sort of a more specific `\033[0`. Try `echo -e "\e[31mfoo\e[39mbar"` for instance, you should see "foo" in red but "bar" in your default terminal color. If the first ANSI escape had defined a background color you woulnd't see any difference between the two parts since the `\e[39m` only resets the text color

Comment: Ah, I see, I understand now, 49 and 39 reset their particular to the default. Was under the impression it had some specific syntax to specify a particular color. That's frustrating.

This almost seems like a console rendering bug, because changing the window size changes the result a bit. Do newlines or tabs create issues when using colors?

Comment: I can't see your current situation/expected situation (I'm on a corporate network that blocks imgur which StackOverflow uses to hosts the images users upload) so I'm not sure i'll be able to help you much more. In my experience though rich text formatting just isn't something you will want to do on a terminal. It might be possible, but you can be sure it will be much more bothersome than basing your solution on a more adapted platform such as a text editor, a web page, your preferred language's GUI toolkit or an IDE

Comment: Ah, ok, I suppose I could explain it a bit, it's the standard black / white windows console. I'm clearly getting sections that need syntax highlighting to work (I'm ripping off mvsc's syntax highlighting). It seems as though parts that trail newlines or tabs render the standard black / white. I'm not resetting back to the default, it just seems to do that on its own. My immediate thought process was, oh there's probably some way to control that particular color like the text sections (hence my confusion about the 39 and 49 escape sequences).

Comment: Using `\e[K` (erase from cursor to end of line) on each line before writing any text seems to help, at least on my mintty packaged with cygwin : `echo -e "\e[41m(tab)foo(linefeed)bar"` displays only foo and bar with a red background, but if I change it into `echo -e "\e[41m\e[K(tab)foo(linefeed)\e[Kbar\e[0m"` I now have the two whole lines with red background, most likely because the terminal now considers it has to "redraw" those cells. I suppose that won't fix the window-resizing problem though

Comment: For the window size change you could [trap WINCH](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/bash/react-on-change-of-terminals-window-size-95e9465d00de435a88da4ac5693a201b) to clear the screen and print your whole text again

Comment: Guess it is console specific, having no luck with `\e[K`, behaves the same whether I add it before or after tabs and newlines, bit of a head scratcher. I'll play around with some other screen clearing codes, see if anything makes a difference.

Comment: Scratch the previous comment, I used 'k' as opposed to upper case 'K'. I ended up using the escape sequence `\033[0K`. It does bug out when the screen resizes, but only in sections w/ newlines back to back, and I'm sure I can hack my around that by injecting some characters in between. Thank you. Feel free to make that an answer for people who come along later.

Comment: Clearing the screen with `\033[2J` will set the background to the current mode for the entire screen on most terminal emulators. That obviates the need to perform a line-by-line erase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\033[39` and `\033[49` are used to reset respectively the text and background color.
 You can test them with the following command :

```
echo -e '\e[43m\e[31mbg&text\e[49mtext\e[39mnone'
```

To have your background color applied to whole lines, I've found you can use the "erase in line" control sequence (`(ESC)[K` for xterm-based terminals) at the start of your lines after the background color control sequence to force the redraw of all the cells in the row with your background color :

```
echo -e '\e[41m\e[Kwhole line with background'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a programming question; OP probably needs a tutorial, which makes it off-topic.  There is no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), either.

"ANSI" (more formally [ECMA-48](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)) defines syntax for control sequences and gives (often terse) descriptions.  The fragment in the question

```
\033[49
\033[39
```

is not a control sequence, because it is incomplete. ECMA-48 requires a *final* character to complete those.  By context in the question, one knows that **`m`** is intended, but that is an assumption. After all, ECMA-48 (and various terminal documents) define other sequences which could have 39 and 49 as parameters (such as the [set-mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-l.1D12) controls).

Now... ECMA-48 is vague (and terse) in this area because there is more than one way to interpret the description

```
Set background color to default
```

and the committee people didn't want to describe the nuances of different terminals.  In a different context, the curses (and ncurses) libraries have to deal with this.  There are a few *terminal capabilities* which are used for this purpose.  The [`terminfo(5)`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Color-Handling) manual page gives some useful information:

> Some basic color capabilities are independent of the color method.  The
>          numeric  capabilities  colors  and pairs specify the maximum numbers of
>          colors and color-pairs that can be displayed  simultaneously.   The  **`op`**
>          (original pair) string resets foreground and background colors to their
>          default values for the terminal.  The **`oc`** string resets  all  colors  or
>          color-pairs  to  their default values for the terminal.  Some terminals
>          (including many PC terminal emulators) erase screen areas with the current  background  color  rather  than  the power-up default background;
>          these should have the boolean capability **`bce`**.

and also mentions a different feature which bears upon this question:

> On some color terminals, colors collide with highlights.  You can  register  these collisions with the **`ncv`** capability.  This is a bit-mask of
>          attributes not to be used when colors are enabled.  The  correspondence
>          with the attributes understood by curses is as follows

That is, the behavior is implementation-dependent, and curses/ncurses provides a way to adjust a terminal description to reflect the differences.  Some of the variations are discussed in the ncurses FAQ [*My terminal shows some uncolored spaces*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#bce_mismatches).  The particular combination of features used in xterm was based on Linux console (see [discussion](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#cause_bce_linux)), which in turn was an imperfect imitation of some earlier terminal whose behavior likely was considered in defining **bce** and **ncv**.

Comment: You'd be right that I needed a tutorial, the issue though is that the description and the behavior of the ansi color syntax gave me the impression I was missing some other sequence with similar syntax to get the effect I was after. Because I couldn't find one documented I went straight here because I was 100% certain someone would know how to get what I was after.

As for a minimal reproducible example, you only need to attempt setting the background color and print some lines of text like in the image example. If someone else were asking this question I'd assume they've done that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only portable way I've found is to write spaces of the correct colour over all those areas. `ESC [ K` is supposed to "erase" to end of line, according to ECMA-48.  Erase has different interpretations. However both `screen` and `tmux` interpret it as clear to default colours (i.e. 39/49), which is black on black terminal, white on white terminal. So unfortunately there seems to be no efficient way to clear areas portably, except by writing spaces all over them.